# Multiple Inserts-Selects inside EF Transaction - SaveChanges fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db2, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

I have a Entity Framework transaction opened and handling multiple insert-select-updates in a sequential chain. The SaveChanges is called on UitOfWork at the very end, but the problem is, when the SaveChanges is called, the "select data" queried entities are also again taken for inserting into db, thereby failing with a DbUpdateException.

```
IUnitOfWorkTransaction transaction = unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

using context1()
{
repository.(Insert into table 1)

repository.(Select data from table 2)
repository.(Select data from table 3)

repository.(Insert into table 4)

repository.(Update table 1 and table 2)
}

unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

As we can see, it uses a sequential chain of events all inside 1 transaction and all repository calls under single dbcontext, but when the SaveChanges is fired, the DbUpdateException is thrown for a table (entity) which is "just" part of the "Select data" query and not inserts / updates.
EF is trying to insert / update / delete data from that table, when it has been just queried initially and not set for insert.

Any help, in setting up the process correct to Save all changes is much appreciated.

Comment: This code doesn't help us to find the exact issue. Please publish your actual code.

Comment: which specific part of information would help? As it would be too much to put entire stuff out here, including entities, their mapping and all that.